# I'm getting "blocked by CORS policy" when I try to call Instagram API using Axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, cors, axios, csrf

I'm trying to fetch some images from my Instagram account in a Laravel application with Vue as front end. When I try to do it in a standalone Vue app, it works well, but when I do so with Laravel, I got a message saying "has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field x-csrf-token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response."

I'm using Laravel 5.8 and the Vue and Axios that comes within in and I'm using Homestead as my localhost server.

I've tried a lot of tips that I found here and on Google but I had no success. Basically, I'm trying the very basic of Axios call

```
        beforeMount() {
            axios.get('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=[MY_ACCESS_TOKEN]').then(response => console.log(response))
        }
```

I already created a Cors middleware on Laravel and tried a lot of headers settings on Axios.

I'm basically trying to retrieve a list of my Instagram posts and bypass that cors / x-csrf error.

Comment: Have you added `x-csrf-token` header to allowed list in the `Cors.php` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AJAX` request to the Instagram API endpoint has to be sent as a `jsonp` request which means the `dataType` of the request has to be `jsonp`.

[This blob](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/COOKBOOK.md#jsonp) in `axios` repository contains an example of sending a request using `jsonp` which is mentioned below.

Install `jsonp` package, if you haven't already.

```
npm install jsonp --save
```

and then;

```
const jsonp = require('jsonp');

jsonp('http://www.example.com/foo', null, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  } else {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Below is an example of sending a request using jQuery method with `jsonp` dataType to the Instagram API endpoint.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=[MY_ACCESS_TOKEN]",
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: @hugolcouto do not forget to Up vote the answer :)

Comment: This suggests switching axios for jQuery. That is a bit counterproductive.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I've installed the jsonp npm package and used it instead of axios. I didn't use jquery on it.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel automatically applies the `X-CSRF-TOKEN` header to all axios requests.  This is so you can communicate with your application without having to pass the CSRF token every time for POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.

**resources/js/bootstrap.js** (default settings)

```js
/**
 * Next we will register the CSRF Token as a common header with Axios so that
 * all outgoing HTTP requests automatically have it attached. This is just
 * a simple convenience so we don't have to attach every token manually.
 */

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

You should be able to remove the offending header by doing something like this:

```js
beforeMount() {

    // create a new instance so we don't delete the csrf token for other requests
    let instance = axios.create();

    // delete the x-csrf-token header
    delete instance.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'];

    // use the new instance to make your get request
    instance.get('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=[MY_ACCESS_TOKEN]')
        .then(response => console.log(response))
}
```